# Python how do I get the download percentage from youtube-dl when im downloading a video

Tags: python, youtube, youtube-dl

I want to get the percentage of the download from youtube-dl module for python, the reason for this is I want to put it into a progress bar in pyqt5. I did not find and documentation on youtube-dl's GitHub or anywhere else on this, would anyone happen to know?

I have not found any successful answers anywhere on google/stack overflow/GitHub.

```py
def downloadYoutube(self):
        self.changeText()
        # try:
        self.lblState.setText('Downloading...')

        url = self.txtURL.text()
        if 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?' not in url:
            buttonReply = QMessageBox.critical(self, 'Error! :(', "{} is an invalid URL".format(url), QMessageBox.Ok, QMessageBox.Ok)
            return
        # if 'https://youtu.be/' not in url:
        #     buttonReply = QMessageBox.critical(self, 'Error! :(', "{} is an invalid URL".format(url), QMessageBox.Ok, QMessageBox.Ok)
        #     return
        if self.radAudio.isChecked() == True:
            ydl_opts = {
                'format': 'bestaudio/best',
                'extractaudio': True,
                'audioformat': "mp3",
                'noplaylist': True,
            }
        else:
            ydl_opts = {
                'noplaylist': True,
            }
        info_dict = youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts).extract_info(url, download = False)
        video_id = info_dict.get("id", None)
        video_title = info_dict.get('title', None)
        self.lblTitle.setText(str(video_title))

        try:
            with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
                self.lblState.setText('Downloading...')
                ydl.download([url])
        except Exception as e:
            self.lblState.setText('')
            buttonReply = QMessageBox.critical(self, 'Error! :(', "Problem downloading {}\n\nError Log:\n{}".format(url, e), QMessageBox.Ok, QMessageBox.Ok)
            return
```

I would expect the percentage to be in a variable form, but I can't seem to extract the percentage from anywhere.

Comment: Could you check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33050960/10515117)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'll share the answer here, as [Marceline](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10515117/marceline) shared a link to the answer, but I'll share it here when you want to put it into a pyqt5 progress bar...

```py
            ydl_opts = {
                'format': 'bestaudio/best',
                'extractaudio': True,
                'audioformat': "mp3",
                'progress_hooks': [self.my_hook],
                'noplaylist': True
            }
    def my_hook(self, d):
        if d['status'] == 'finished':
            file_tuple = os.path.split(os.path.abspath(d['filename']))
            print("Done downloading {}".format(file_tuple[1]))
        if d['status'] == 'downloading':
            p = d['_percent_str']
            p = p.replace('%','')
            self.progress.setValue(float(p))
            print(d['filename'], d['_percent_str'], d['_eta_str'])
```